# Get protected tweets with Twitter API

Tags: c#, java, api, twitter, protected

At this point, most of you know that Twitter fixed the problem with Protected tweets not being protected at all.

I'm looking everywhere and have only found some links to oAuth for authentication. But what i can't find is a way to capture protected tweets. To make the question a little bit simpler. Can somebody help me with a bit of code to retrieve my own private tweets?

**Situation (C# and/or Java will help me):**

My **own** tweets are protected and i would like to Fetch those protected tweets and put them in.. say: A text file. What is the best way to achieve this?

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: "have only found some links to oAuth for authentication" Have you set up oAuth authentication for your app then? And it's still not returning the protected tweets?

Comment: I've set up an authentication, but i can't figure out how to use it.. It's pretty new to me and don't really know where to start with oAuth.

But based on your reaction.. I should be able to get protected tweets with just using oAuth?

Comment: I would have thought so - as long as you're authenticated as an account that has access then I'd expect you could read the tweets. But I've never tried that myself, sorry. You could try using a twitter library that has the oAuth built in, e.g. TweetSharp, if you're not already if that would make it simpler.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll start trying that out. But if you or somebody else has more info or sample code.. that might help speed the process up a little. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment above said. Tweetshark is the way to go.

You will first need to make a twitter application.
Then follow this documentation:

http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/documentation

It will explain how to authenticate with Twitter with a mobile app, silverlight or a normal website. Pick correctly !

To get your tweets you simply need to use the `TwitterService`you used and do this:

```
List<TwitterStatus> lstTweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline().ToList();
```

Hope this helps abit.